# Move the View like tableViewcell

Tags: iphone

what i can do to move the title like "hh" and "asdasd" to move from one place to another same like MoveRowAtIndexPath and inner task like "111" and "sdfdsf" also can move.
      I am Using the ViewForHeaderinSection to display the title and in cellForAtIndexPath the inner part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

implement the necessary UITableview methods for moving?

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
```

Comment: for moving row it will be ok but i want to change the upper means "hh"  this i am setting the ViewForHeaderInSection. and i want to change that.

Comment: ah ok, you want to change the header name into the table most above row. Well do you implement the viewforheader tableview method?
In that method you can simply set it to what you want, so within that method check what the top-row text is?